# Need to select ONLY if visiting one location

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following SQL, it was looking at only those vouchers from location_ID = 5. How can I code that, I ONLY want from a Patient_ID who ONLY visited location_ID 5?

```
SELECT "Vouchers"."Patient_ID", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Number",  
       "Practitioners"."Practitioner_ID", "Practitioners"."First_Name",   
       "Practitioners"."Last_Name", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_First_Name", 
       "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Last_Name", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_DOB", 
       "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Sex", "Vouchers"."Carrier_ID", 
       "Vouchers"."Billing_Date", "Vouchers"."Patient_Policy_ID", 
       "Vouchers"."Location_ID"
FROM   ("Ntier_70751"."PM"."vwGenPatInfo" "vwGenPatInfo" 
INNER JOIN "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Vouchers" "Vouchers" 
ON "vwGenPatInfo"."Account_ID"="Vouchers"."Account_ID") 
INNER JOIN "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Practitioners" "Practitioners" 
ON "Vouchers"."Actual_Prov_Practitioner_ID"="Practitioners"."Practitioner_ID"
-- 
WHERE  "Vouchers"."Location_ID"=5
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, learn to use table aliases so your queries are easier to write and to read.  And don't escape table and column names unless you have to.

Comment: Do a conditional aggregation on the `Location_ID`, group by the `Patient_Id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. I also got rid of all those unneeded double quotes and used proper aliases.

```
SELECT V.Patient_ID
    , gpi.Patient_Number
    , P.Practitioner_ID
    , P.First_Name
    , P.Last_Name
    , gpi.Patient_First_Name
    , gpi.Patient_Last_Name
    , gpi.Patient_DOB
    , gpi.Patient_Sex
    , V.Carrier_ID
    , V.Billing_Date
    , V.Patient_Policy_ID
    , V.Location_ID
FROM Ntier_70751.PM.vwGenPatInfo gpi 
INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Vouchers V ON gpi.Account_ID = V.Account_ID 
INNER JOIN Ntier_70751.PM.Practitioners P ON V.Actual_Prov_Practitioner_ID = P.Practitioner_ID
cross apply
(
    select V2.Account_ID
    from Ntier_70751.PM.Vouchers V2
    where V2.Account_ID = V.Account_ID

    group by V2.Account_ID
    HAVING MAX(Location_ID) = 5
        AND MIN(Location_ID) = 5
) x
```

Comment: Could you do it with a distinct query?  That was my thought - a sub query that runs a distinct query on locations to return only 5?

Comment: @MageeWorld not sure what you mean. A distinct query will limit the number of rows which I don't think will help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition as say;

```
WHERE "Vouchers"."Location_ID" = 5
```

Comment: That will return anybody who has at least one visit to 5, the OP wants people who ONLY visited 5.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with not exists

```
SELECT "Vouchers"."Patient_ID", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Number",  
       "Practitioners"."Practitioner_ID", "Practitioners"."First_Name",   "Practitioners"."Last_Name", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_First_Name", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Last_Name", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_DOB", "vwGenPatInfo"."Patient_Sex", "Vouchers"."Carrier_ID", "Vouchers"."Billing_Date", "Vouchers"."Patient_Policy_ID", "Vouchers"."Location_ID"
FROM "Ntier_70751"."PM"."vwGenPatInfo" "vwGenPatInfo" INNER JOIN 
     "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Vouchers" "Vouchers"
     ON "vwGenPatInfo"."Account_ID" = "Vouchers"."Account_ID" INNER JOIN
        "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Practitioners" "Practitioners"
     ON "Vouchers"."Actual_Prov_Practitioner_ID" = "Practitioners"."Practitioner_ID"
 WHERE  "Vouchers"."Location_ID"=5
   and not exists (select 1 
                    FROM "Ntier_70751"."PM"."Vouchers" "Vouchers2"
                     WHERE "Vouchers2"."Patient_ID" = "Vouchers2"."Patient_ID" 
                       AND "Vouchers2"."Location_ID"<>5)
```

Comment: This would produce the desired results but is nonSARGable. You have a <> in your subquery so it has to evaluate every single row.

Comment: @SeanLange - It depends. I'm guessing if there is a low number of patients with location_id = 5 only those patients would be evaluated on the subquery (if patient_id is indexed). Anyway, it's hard to know without the schema specification.

Comment: It is dependent on the number of rows in Vouchers. And no matter what happens when you have <> in your where clause it will cause a scan.

Comment: @SeanLange It would be nice if could see both explain plans. I'm not sure if your having Max(Location_ID) is going to be sargable.

Comment: Agreed. It may or may not. Hard to know for sure. As with most things there are many ways to accomplish the desired output. We have presented two of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just using the condition 'WHERE "Vouchers"."Location_ID" = 5'will return all Patient_IDs that visited the that location at least once but not exclusively. There are several ways to do it but the cleanest would be using  having max (location_id) <5 and min (location_id) >5